# Count "cool" divisors of given number N

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I'm trying to solve pretty complex problem with divisors and number theory.

Namely for a given number *m* we can say that *k* is cool divisor if *k*<*m* *k*|*m* (k divides m evenly), and for a given number *n* the number k^n (k to the power of n) is not divisor of *m*. Let s(x) - number of cool divisors of x.

Now for given a and b we should find D = s(a) + s(a+1) + s(a+2) + s(a+3) + ... + s(a+b).

Limits for all values:
(1 <= a <= 10^6), (1 <= b <= 10^7), (2<=n<=10)

**Example**

Let's say a=32, b=1, n=3;

x = 32, n = 3 divisors of 32 are {1,2,4,8,16,32}. However only {4,8,16} fill the conditions so s(32) = 3

x = 33, n = 3 divisors of 33 are {1,3,11,33}. Only the numbers {3,11} fill the conditions so s(33)=2;

D = s(32) + s(33) = 3 + 2 = 5

**What I have tried**

We should answer all those questions for 100 test cases in 3 seconds time limit.

I have two ideas, the first one: I iterate in the interval [a, a+b] and for each value i in the range I check how many cool divisors are there for that value, we can check this in O(sqrt(N)) if the function for getting number of power of N is considered as O(1) so the total function for this is O(B*sqrt(B)).

The second one, I'm now sure if it will work and how fast it will be. First I do a precomputation, I have a for loop that iterates from 1 to N, where N = 10^7
and now in the range [2, N] for each number whose divisor is i, where i is in the range [2,N] and I check if i to the power of n is not divisor of j then we update that the number j has one more cool divisor. With this I think that the complexity will be O(NlogN) and for the answers O(B).

Comment: Is this a problem from spoj.com ?

Comment: I'm not sure, it may be because I faced it on one training session, can you please post linko from spoj?

Answer (score 1):

Your first idea works but you can improve it.

Instead of checking all numbers from 1 to sqrt(N) whether they are cool divisors, you can factorize N=*p0^q0*p1^q1*p2^q2...pk^qk*. Then the number of cool divisors should then be ***(q0+1)(q1+1)...(qk+1) - (q0/n+1)(q1/n+1)...(qk/n+1)***.

So you can first preprocess and find out all the prime numbers using some existing algo like **Sieve of Eratosthenes** and for each number N between [a,a+b] you do a factorization. The complexity should be roughly O(BlogB).

Your second idea works as well.

For each number i between [2,a+b], you can just check the multiples of i between [a,a+b] and see whether i is a cool divisor of those multiples. The complexity should be O(BlogB) as well. Some tricks can be played in this idea to speed up the program is that, once **you don't need to use divide/mod operations from time to time to check whether i is a cool divisor**. You can compute the first number m between [a, a+b] that i^n|m. This m should be **m=ceiling(a/(i^n))(i^n)**. And then you know i^n|m+p*i does not hold for p between [1,i^(n-1) - 1] and holds for p=i^n-1. Basically, you know i is not a cool divisor every i^(n-1) multiples, and you do not need to use divide/mod to figure it out, which will speed the program up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however can you give me link to help me learn how to make factorization in O(logN) time complexity with having the sieve of eratostenes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @someone12321, with having the sieve of eratosthenes, you find out all prime numbers within the range, and then you can just divide the original number by the prime numbers one by one. The complexity is roughly O(logN). You can also play some tricks to make it even faster, you can refer to http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7262